# Invert brace from { to } and vise versa

Tags: javascript

I have a string with `{` and `}` how can I take all of them and reverse them, so all `{` become `}` and `}` become `{`?

I can't do this:

```
str = str.replace("}", "{");
str = str.replace("{", "}");
```

because that will make **A** face the same way as **B** then it will replace **B** which will all change them to the same direction.

I tried doing this:

```
str = str.replace(["{", "}"], ["}", "{"]);
```

But that just doesn't seem to do anything (not even error out).

So, what can I do to invert them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a regexp with a callback function to solve this:

```
str.replace(/\{|\}/g, function(match) {
    return match == "}" ? "{" : "}";
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Using a temporary string is prone to a bug.

Comment: This also replaces more than once, because of the "g" modifer

Answer (score 6):

You can use a temporary string that will definitely be unique to do the swap:

```
str = str.replace("}", "TEMP_HOLDER");
str = str.replace("{", "}");
str = str.replace("TEMP_HOLDER", "{");
```

But it's prone to a bug if the string contains the temp string and it also doesn't replace more than one occurrence. I'd suggest using Erik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29593503/188246).

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to something else in the first pass, and then convert to what you want after you've made the other conversions.

```
str = str.replace("{", "_###_");
str = str.replace("}", "{");
str = str.replace("_###_", "}");
```

Of course, the *something else* will need to be something that won't otherwise be in your string. You could use "\r\n" if you are sure you string won't contain newlines.

Answer (score -1):

You could go with a two stage solution:

```
str = str.replace("}", "~");
str = str.replace("{", ",");

str = str.replace("~", "{");
str = str.replace(",", "}");
```